# InputStream empty after validation - javax.xml.validation.Validator;

Tags: java

I'm not figuring out why the InputStream parameter is empty after the validate instruction in the source code below.

```
    public boolean validateXMLSchema(InputStream xmlStream) {
        try {
            XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(xmlStream);

            reader = new StreamReaderDelegate(reader) {
                public int next() throws XMLStreamException {
                    int n = super.next();
                    return n;
                }
            };

            SchemaFactory factory =
                    SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xsd_example.xsd")));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator(); 
            validator.validate(new StAXSource(reader));  //InputStream empty after this instruction
        } catch (SAXException | IOException | XMLStreamException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error message...", e);

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Could somebody help me out please?

Thanks in advance,
Mika

Answer (score 0):

Probably your validator reads the InputStream

From
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stax/StAXSource.html

> StAXSources are consumed during processing and are not reusable.